# How do I set short URL's for MediaWiki?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mediawiki-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide to install mediawiki version 1.27.0.  The install went great, and everything is working.

Currently in the url it still has the index.php in the url, like this: `http://example.com/index.php/Main_Page`

There is documentation [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache#Plan), and [here](https://sharkysoft.com/wiki/how_to_remove_index.php_from_MediaWiki_URLs), but there are sections of these instructions that don't make sense to me.

Here's what I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache2
- mediawiki 1.27.0
- My VM is on Amazon AWS

---

I'll go through the instructions, and list the problems I'm having.

**1. In the instructions they assume that your mediawiki install is setup in `/w`.**

Well, mine is installed here `/var/www/html/`

**2. Find the right apache2 files**

I have root access so I'm assuming I will be using two files `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for the `AllowOverride All`, and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to edit anything related to the VirtualHost section.

**3. Setting the rewrite rules**

In my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file, in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section, I added these lines

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]`

I understand that this shouldn't work with my setup, because it's using the /wiki, and /w filepaths, and those don't even exist, but I'm not sure what I should put.

**4. Change LocalSettings.php**

This step also has me confused for the same reason.  It says to set `$wgScriptPath = "/w";`, which is a directory I don't have, and set `$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";`, which is not only a directory I don't have, but that variable doesn't even exist in the LocalSettings.php file.

---

I think if I understood the first step, of changing my directory to `/w`, then I could get the rest, but obviously, I can't change /var/www/html, to /w, without breaking everything.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

For all who are **not running MediaWiki in the default subdirectoy** on your HOST (means not like `/w/` or `/wiki/`) configure your `.htaccess` like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

And add the article path to your `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgArticlePath = "/$1";
```

Comment: Most of the tutorials I've found that go over creating a mediawiki, don't actually require an .htaccess file (or at least don't go over its creation).  For example, the one I used [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mediawiki-on-ubuntu-14-04).  Would I just need to create the ```.htaccess``` file in my root directory, for example, in the instructions above, the ```/var/www/html/``` directory?  I was hesitant to create one, because I wasn't sure how to tell apache to use it, and I really haven't wanted to break the site.

Comment: @trueCamelType you have to create an `.htaccess` file in the moment you want to use SEO friendy URLs. `.htaccess` files are enabled by default while using apache. The tutorial you linked does not configure seo-friendy URL, so you dont need a htaccess file here. Place the `.htaccess` file in your vhost root server which should be `/var/www/html/` on linux/apache by default. Please mark this answer as right if it does solve your problem.